# Need Help in finding 2 seperate contours instead of a combined contour in MICR code

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, computer-vision, contour, noise-reduction

I an running OCR on bank cheques using                                 [pyimagesearch tutorial](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/07/31/bank-check-ocr-opencv-python-part-ii) to detect micr code. The code used in the tutorial detects group contours & character contours from a reference image containing symbols.

[image: reference image]
In the tutorial when finding the **contours** for symbol below

[image: good resolution symbol]

the code uses an built-in python iterator to iterate over the contours (here 3 seperate contours) and combined to give a character for recognition purposes.

---

But in the cheque dataset that I use, I have the symbol with low resolution

[image]
The actual bottom of the cheque is :
[image: cheque number]

which causes the iterator to consider the contour-2 & contour-3 as a single contour. Due to this the iterator iterates over the character following the above symbol (here '0') and prepares a incorrect template to match with the reference symbols. You can see the code below for better understanding.

I know here noise in the image is a factor, but is it possible to reduce the noise & also find the exact contour to detect the symbol?

I tried using noise reduction techniques like `cv2.fastNlMeansDenoising` & `cv2.GaussianBlur` before `cv2.findContours` step the contours 2&3 are detected as single contour instead of 2 seperate contours.
Also I tried altering the `cv2.findContours' parameters

Below is the working code where the characters are iterated for better understanding of python builtin iterator:

```
def extract_digits_and_symbols(image, charCnts, minW=5, minH=10):
    # grab the internal Python iterator for the list of character
    # contours, then  initialize the character ROI and location
    # lists, respectively
    charIter = charCnts.__iter__()
    rois = []
    locs = []

    # keep looping over the character contours until we reach the end
    # of the list
    while True:
        try:
            # grab the next character contour from the list, compute
            # its bounding box, and initialize the ROI
            c = next(charIter)
            (cX, cY, cW, cH) = cv2.boundingRect(c)
            roi = None

            # check to see if the width and height are sufficiently
            # large, indicating that we have found a digit
            if cW >= minW and cH >= minH:
                # extract the ROI
                roi = image[cY:cY + cH, cX:cX + cW]
                rois.append(roi)
                cv2.imshow('roi',roi)
                cv2.waitKey(0)
                locs.append((cX, cY, cX + cW, cY + cH))

            # otherwise, we are examining one of the special symbols
            else:
                # MICR symbols include three separate parts, so we
                # need to grab the next two parts from our iterator,
                # followed by initializing the bounding box
                # coordinates for the symbol
                parts = [c, next(charIter), next(charIter)]
                (sXA, sYA, sXB, sYB) = (np.inf, np.inf, -np.inf,
                                        -np.inf)

                # loop over the parts
                for p in parts:
                    # compute the bounding box for the part, then
                    # update our bookkeeping variables
                    # c = next(charIter)
                    # (cX, cY, cW, cH) = cv2.boundingRect(c)
                    # roi = image[cY:cY+cH, cX:cX+cW]
                    # cv2.imshow('symbol', roi)
                    # cv2.waitKey(0)
                    # roi = None
                    (pX, pY, pW, pH) = cv2.boundingRect(p)
                    sXA = min(sXA, pX)
                    sYA = min(sYA, pY)
                    sXB = max(sXB, pX + pW)
                    sYB = max(sYB, pY + pH)

                # extract the ROI
                roi = image[sYA:sYB, sXA:sXB]
                cv2.imshow('symbol', roi)
                cv2.waitKey(0)
                rois.append(roi)
                locs.append((sXA, sYA, sXB, sYB))

        # we have reached the end of the iterator; gracefully break
        # from the loop
        except StopIteration:
            break

    # return a tuple of the ROIs and locations
    return (rois, locs)
```

edit: contour 2 & 3 instead of contours 1 & 2

Comment: Who stops you applying sharpening algo to character before countour detection ? Aften sharpening your image you'll get something [like this](https://i.imgur.com/0APHIEz.png)

Comment: If you can share steps to sharpen the above image, I can mark the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to find the right threshold value, instead of using `cv2.THRESH_OTSU`. It seems should be possible to find a suitable threshold from the provided example. If you can't find the threshold value that works for all images, you can try morphological closing on the threshold result with structuring element with 1-pixel width.

Edit (steps):

For threshold, you need to find appropriate value by hand, in your image threhsold value 100 seems to work:

```
i = cv.imread('image.png')
g = cv.cvtColor(i, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
_, tt = cv.threshold(g, 100, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
```

as for closing variant:

```
_, t = cv.threshold(g, 0,255,cv.THRESH_BINARY_INV | cv.THRESH_OTSU)
kernel = np.ones((12,1), np.uint8)
c = cv.morphologyEx(t, cv.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
```

Note that I used `import cv2 as cv`. I also used opening instead of closing since in the example they inverted colors during thresholding

Comment: Can you share the steps? I can then mark it as the answer

Comment: I am failing to detect the symbol from the cheque image

Comment: The kernel `np.ones((12,1), np.uint8)` works fine for only symbol detection. Instead I used np.ones((3,3)) for a more accurate detection. Thank you for your time @zteffi